# How to do Node.js Routing(maybe using express) in Lambda Function invoking API Gateway?

Tags: amazon-web-services, express, aws-lambda, routes, aws-api-gateway

I have AWS Api Gateway, that invokes Lambda function on AWS. How would I achieve Routing using express or any module which could work. Following is my basic lambda function

```
exports.handler = (event, context, callback)
{
    callback(null, 'Hello From Lambda)
}
```

Comment: Perhaps the `aws-lambda-router` package can be used: https://www.npmjs.com/package/aws-lambda-router

Comment: @user3601546 Thank you, that's exactly what I needed

Comment: @user3601546  Please make it as an answer so that  can mark it right

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I suggest to use the `aws-lambda-router` package.

It's a library for AWS Lambda providing routing for API Gateway, Proxy Integrations, SNS and S3 Events.

More info: https://npmjs.com/package/aws-lambda-router